# 'array' is unavailable: please construct an Array from your lazy sequence: Array(...)

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I updated Xcode to 9 beta, I have fixed my code to swift 2.

Now, I have an error "'array' is unavailable: please construct an Array from your lazy sequence: Array(...)" on the following code.

```
var dic: [String: String] = Dictionary<String, String>(minimumCapacity: 8)
dic.values.array// error
```

How should I write instead of this code?

```
Array(dic.values)
```

This code is correct?

I could not find the Apple's document about LazyMapCollection. Thank you.

Comment: `Array(dic.values)` *is* correct. Did you try it?

Answer (score 23):

Like this:

```
var dic: [String: String] = Dictionary<String, String>(minimumCapacity: 8)
let values: [String] = [String](dic.values)
```

Comment: Or just `let values = Array(dic.values)`.