# 'array' is unavailable: please construct an Array from your lazy sequence: Array(...) error

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

Just updated to swift 2.0 and I am having an error.

The error I am getting is: **'array' is unavailable: please construct an Array from your lazy sequence: Array(...)**

My code is:

```
            if let credentialStorage = session.configuration.URLCredentialStorage {
            let protectionSpace = NSURLProtectionSpace(
                host: URL!.host!,
                port: URL!.port?.integerValue ?? 0,
                `protocol`: URL!.scheme,
                realm: URL!.host!,
                authenticationMethod: NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic
            )
// ERROR------------------------------------------------↓
            if let credentials = credentialStorage.credentialsForProtectionSpace(protectionSpace)?.values.array {
// ERROR------------------------------------------------↑
                for credential: NSURLCredential in (credentials) {
                    components.append("-u \(credential.user!):\(credential.password!)")
                }
            } else {
                if let credential = delegate.credential {
                    components.append("-u \(credential.user!):\(credential.password!)")
                }
            }
        }
```

Would anyone know how to convert this line of code to be updated for Swift 2.0?

`if let credentials = credentialStorage.credentialsForProtectionSpace(protectionSpace)?.values.array`

Comment: What version is your xcode?

Comment: It works in my playground.

Comment: @pixyzehn this is version 7 beta 6

Comment: @Bills trying to change `values.array` to `values.elements`

Answer (score 9):

As the error states, you should construct `Array`. Try:

```
if let credentials = (credentialStorage?.credentialsForProtectionSpace(protectionSpace)?.values).map(Array.init) {
    //...
}
```

In Swift1.2, `values` on `Dictionary<Key, Value>` returns `LazyForwardCollection<MapCollectionView<[Key : Value], Value>>` type that has `.array` property returning `Array<Value>`.

In Swift2, `values` on `Dictionary<Key, Value>` returns `LazyMapCollection<[Key : Value], Value>`, and the `.array` property is abandoned because we can construct `Array` with `Array(dict.values)`.

In this case, since `credentialStorage?.credentialsForProtectionSpace(protectionSpace)?.values` end up with `Optional` type, we cannot simply `Array(credentialStorage?.cre...)`. Instead, if you want a `Array`, we should use `map()` on `Optional`.

But, in this particular case, you can use `credentialStorage?.credentialsForProtectionSpace(protectionSpace)?.values` as is.

Try:

```
if let credentials = credentialStorage?.credentialsForProtectionSpace(protectionSpace)?.values {
    for credential in credentials {
        //...
    }
}
```

This works because `LazyMapCollection` conforms to `SequenceType`.

Comment: `(dict.keys).map(Array.init)` did not work for me (I ended up with `Element` inference errors) but `[MyType](dict.keys)` worked (found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32243072/63582)

Answer (score 0):

Use the initializer in Swift 2.0

```
guard let values = credentialStorage?.credentialsForProtectionSpace(protectionSpace)?.values else { return }
let credentials = Array<NSURLCredential>(values)
for credential in credentials {
    // `credential` will be a non-optional of type `NSURLCredential`
}
```